# How can I install the "OS" package of python using the anaconda prompt?

Tags: python, operating-system, package, anaconda, prompt

So this question is pretty easy, but I didn't find a great answer. In my program, I want to import the OS package using: `import os`.
Well, how can I import this package using the anaconda prompt? I tried `conda install os` and `pip install os` and it didn't work. Can anyone help me?

Comment: What happened when you tried `import os`?

Comment: I'm using a server to run my code (serv of another place, greater than mine) and when I try to execute "conda install os" this returns an error. The error is too long for a comment. Do you really want to see it?

Comment: I saw that "os" is a standard package in python3. That's true?

Comment: Yes, hence my question. Unless you have something really weird going on there you shouldn't need to install it.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answers!!!

Comment: The "random" package belongs to that same situation?

Comment: The standard library is well documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`os` is already installed with your python package. You just have to import it into your python files, you can do this by `import os`.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer!